# Issue during the spring upgrade from 1.2 version to 4.1.1

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Below is the issue I am facing during starting up of the server.

> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '2' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: 'www.springframework.org', port: '80'

I thought that the issue might be with the xsd.I had made the respective change but still unable to resolve it.Can anyone help me out in solving the problem

Here's my application context xml file

**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"     "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">    
<beans>    
   <bean id="cdqiPerformanceMonitor"        
   class="com.tms.cdqi.framework.aop.interceptor.CDQIPerformanceMonitorInterceptor"         />
<bean  id="cdqiApplicationContextFactory"class="com.tms.cdqi.framework.context.CDQIAppl    icationContextFactoryImpl" />  
<bean  id="commandInvoker"class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionPr    oxyFactoryBean"  
lazy-init="true">  
<property name="jndiName">  
<value>ejb/CommandInvokerLocal</value>  
</property>
<property name="businessInterface">
<value>  
com.tms.cdqi.application.command.invoker.CommandInvoker  
</value>  
</property>  
</bean>  
</beans>**
```

Comment: What does your `applicationContext.xml` file look like? It looks like there is a reference to 'www.springframework.org' there which is not valid anymore.

Comment: @Jesper My application context xml contains doctype not XSD's. Here is the below content in my xml  .<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

Comment: Please don't add code as a comment but as edit to your original question. To fix your problem don't use the dtd but use the xsd namespaces.

Comment: @Deinum Sure i'll follow your suggestion. I saw the solution you had provided in other post.I tried solution you gave with the xsdversions but still same problem.Is it mandatory to provide the xsd versions?

Comment: No it is even recommended to use the version less ones. Please post your xml file, or at least the header. (And please as edit to your question).

Answer (score 0):

**As Per Denium suggestion I replaced my context xml DTD with versionless XSD 
Thanks Deinum**